# Read voltage (isolated circuit) from 24S Li-ion battery pack and output 0-5 V signal

Tags: analog, lithium-ion, isolation, electric-vehicle

I am finishing up a EV-conversion and everything works well except the SoC display.

The BMS I am using outputs 0-5 V to indicate the SoC but the output pin for this signal is broken from the previous owner. The plan was to use this output but now I want to make a circuit to replace this function.

The SoC indicator in the car is a re-built standard 0-5 V voltmeter (like the ones usually found on power supplies or similar).

I am trying to come up with a simple circuit that reads the voltage of the battery pack, isolates the signal from chassis ground and outputs 0-5V (0-100% SoC), either as a analog signal or as discrete steps (at least 8 steps). The low voltage side of the circuit can be powered by 12V. Whatever I come up with becomes very complex.

The best I can come up with right now is a voltage divider, a isolated solid state relay, a micro controller which takes the isolated signal and outputs 0-5 V PWM signal (and MOSFET?).

So my question is if anyone knows a neater way of doing this. It doesn't matter if the components are of the more expensive variety, as long as I don't have to buy a new BMS.

[image: Block diagram of circuit]

Comment: Using a cell's voltage as a state-of-charge indicator is notoriously inaccurate.  It depends on load, a lot, and temperature, a little.  If the BMS uses a coloumb-counter or similar, reliable, method, then you really want to fix it or replace it rather than doing something hinky that'll tell you a lot more about the current draw on the battery pack than on its actual state of charge.